# #error inside of #define - Possible in C++ (generate error WHEN calling macro MyMacro IF some constant is not defined)?

Tags: c++, c, macros, conditional-compilation

I want to define the macro, that based on some condition (existence of `#define INITED`, not the parameter of the macro) will return value, or generate compiler's error, like:

```
#error Not initialized!
```

I've tried (for `myIdea.h`):

```
#ifdef INITED
    #define MyMacro(x) x->method(); //something with x
#else
    #define MyMacro(x) #error Not initalized!
#endif
```

But that code generates error (not the one I wanted to) `expected macro format parameter`.

**Note, that I don't want that code** (working, but doing bit different thing):

```
#ifdef INITED
    #define MyMacro(x) x->method(); //something with x
#else
    #error Not initalized!
#endif
```

The code above will geneate error just when INITED won't be defined. I want to generate error only **when I call to the `MyMacro()` AND  INITED has not been yet defined**.

I'm not the slave to the first code, but I want the result to work exactly the way I've described above (**generate error WHEN calling macro *MyMacro* IF constant *inited* is not defined**).

Comment: I'm fairly certain this isn't possible. This would require multiple passes through the code by the preprocessor, and I'm fairly sure it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. The preprocessor is just a very simple thing, it does not parse nested macros like that. The second pound (`#`) would not be understood as a nested macro by the preprocessor. The argument is pretty much handled as raw string.

You could however look into static assert with C++11 and on instead of your `#error` directive. You would be writing then something like this:

```
#ifdef INITED
    #define MyMacro(x) x->method(); //something with x
#else
    #define MyMacro(x) static_assert(false, "Not initalized!");
#endif
```

Comment: I see. But is there a way to achieve what I want in some other way? I don't know exactly what you meant by "two-stage preprocessing".

Comment: @PolGraphic: use static assert.